# OpenCV imwrite, the colors are wrong: Which argument for convertTo/cvColor do I use?

Tags: android, opencv, java-native-interface

Okay, so I've been trying and searching online, but I can't find this.

I have:

1. OpenCV4Android which I am using in a mixed fashion: Java and Native.
2. a Mat obtained with

   `capture.retrieve(mFrame, Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_COLOR_FRAME_RGBA);`

This **can not** be changed to Native because it is someone else's library and it is entirely built in non-native way.

1. Native  methods to which I pass this Mat by using `mFrame.nativeObj` and using:

   ```
   JNIEXPORT int JNICALL Java_com_... ( ...jlong addr ... )
   {

       Mat& mrgba = *((Mat*)addr);

       // do stuff

       imwrite( mrgba, ... );
   }
   ```

Now... I use this matrix and then I write it with `imwrite`, all in this native part. Although imwrite does write a file, its colors are all wrong. Red where they should be white, green where they should be black and purple where they should be the color of my table i.e. yellowish. Now, instead of blindly trying `cvColor` and `convertTo`, I'd rather **know** stuff.

What is the number of channels, type, channel order and whatnot that I should know about a frame that was first retrieved with

```
capture.retrieve(mFrame, Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_COLOR_FRAME_RGBA);
```

and then passed through JNI to native OpenCV? Effectively, what conversions do I need to do for **native** imwrite to behave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the image obtained with

```
capture.retrieve(mFrame, Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_COLOR_FRAME_RGBA);
```

needs to be converted like so:

```
cvtColor(mrgba, mbgr, CV_YCrCb2RGB, 4);
```

in order for `imwrite` to correctly output an image to SD Card.

I don't understand why (`imwrite` is supposed to accept BGR images), but at least this answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
capture.retrieve(mFrame, Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_COLOR_FRAME_BGRA);
```

coz OpenCV reads images with blue , green and red channel instead of red,green, blue..

Comment: I do not wish to do this. If I do, however, the image that imwrite writes is all in shades of green, no red or blue to be found. (Not to mention that of course the display in the activity is also wrongly colored.)

Comment: its diffcult to guess channel order from a frame...however according to docs OpenCV always reads image in BGR order...so you can play with cvtColor() and once you get the desired result you can try to explain it for better understanding...

Comment: I've tried all sorts of conversions and none work, hence the question here. I don't intend to blindly try out all combinations of cvtColor unless there's no other option.